# Symfony 2 Access Control to Objects in View

Tags: view, symfony, access-control

In views, I can use

```
if ($view['security']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) :
```

To check if the user has a certain role. But what about objects?

For example: when a user is viewing his/her post, I want to show an edit/delete button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a twig template you can use the `is_granted` function, see [Access control in templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control-in-templates) for more information.

To apply it to ACL you can just do:

```
{% if is_granted('EDIT', post) %}
    Show buttons here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I suppose it can be applied to PHP too? Also if I want to check privilege instead of Role, I suppose I could do `$view['security']->isGranted('VIEW', $post)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't realise you were using PHP view not Twig. The `isGranted` method on `SecurityContext` takes a ACL parameter like you say `isGranted('VIEW', $post)`.